# canvas.drawImage is giving blank screenshot in chrome but not in FF

Tags: javascript, mediadevices

I want to take screenshot using getDisplayMedia, but its giving me blank image.

```
  document
    .getElementById("takeScreenshot")
    .addEventListener("click", async () => {
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      const video = document.createElement("video");

      try {
        const captureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia();
        video.srcObject = captureStream;
        video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", (e) => {
          canvas.width = 600; //e.path[0]?.videoWidth; // set its size to the one of the video
          canvas.height = 600; //e.path[0]?.videoHeight; // video.videoHeight;
          context.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
          const frame = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          captureStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());

          const img = document.createElement("img");
          img.src = frame;
          document.body.append(img);
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error: " + err);
      }
    });
```

see issue on demo output: https://zm3kiy.csb.app/
code: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-wright-zm3kiy?file=/index.html:324-1403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you simply need to call `await video.play();` instead of relying on the `"loadedmetadata"`.

The code below works for me.

```js
document.body.onclick = async () => {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const video = document.createElement("video");

  // Capture media stream.
  const captureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia();
  video.srcObject = captureStream;

  // Play it.
  await video.play();

  // Draw to canvas.
  canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
  canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
  canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, 0, 0);
  document.body.append(canvas);

  // Stop stream.
  captureStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to wait for the `loadedmetadata` event before you can draw the video on the canvas. You can do this by adding an event listener to the video element.

```js
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, window.width, window.height);
  const frame = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  captureStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
  
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = frame;
  document.body.append(img);
});
```

Comment: Now working in FF but not in chrome, see https://zm3kiy.csb.app/